# Python rock, paper, scissors game. not always give correct answers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple ***Rock, Paper, Scissors*** game in **python 3.4** and it works to a certain degree but some time i get an output of "You Won Rock crushes Rock" even though i thought i have stop this from happening and only allowed certain outcomes of the code with my elif and if statements. So can anyone tell me why isn't this working sometimes. :)

```
import random

count = 0
OPTIONS = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    # then check if the user lose's, wins ties

def computer():
    return random.choice(OPTIONS)

print("\n"+"-=-"*11)
print("Welcome to ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS")
print("              GAME")
print("   It's you Vs. the computer!")
print("-=-"*11)
while True:
    user = input("What do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors: ").lower()
    if user in OPTIONS:
        # Possible user time a user can succeeds rock beats sicissor, sicissors cuts paper, paper covers rock
        if user == computer():
            print("tie")

        elif user == 'rock' and computer() == 'scissors':
            print("\nYou Won! {} crushes {}".format(user.title(), computer().title()))

        elif user == 'scissors' and computer() =='rock':
            print("\nComputer Won! {} crushes {}".format(computer().title(), user.title() ))

        elif user == 'scissors' and computer() == 'paper':
            print("\nYou Won! {} cuts {}".format(user.title(), computer().title()))

        elif user == 'paper' and computer() == 'scissors':
            print("\nComputer Won! {} cuts {}".format(computer().title(), user.title()))

        elif user == 'paper' and computer() == 'rock':
            print("\nYou Won! {} covers {}".format(user.title(), computer().title()))

        elif user == 'rock' and computer() == 'paper':
            print("\nComputer Won! {} covers {}".format(computer().title(), user.title()))


    else:
        print("\nMake sure you choose ethier Rock, Paper or Scissors")
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    elif user == 'rock' and computer() == 'scissors':
        print("\nYou Won! {} crushes {}".format(user.title(), computer().title()))
```

Every time you call `computer()`, it generates a completely new value, independent of any previous calls. For example, in the code above it's entirely possible that the first `computer()` call returns "scissors", and the second one returns "rock".

Call `computer()` only once in the loop, and store the result. Then use that value for the rest of your code.

```
while True:
    user = input("What do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors: ").lower()
    if user in OPTIONS:
        computer_move = computer()
        # Possible user time a user can succeeds rock beats sicissor, sicissors cuts paper, paper covers rock
        if user == computer_move:
            print("tie")

        elif user == 'rock' and computer_move == 'scissors':
            print("\nYou Won! {} crushes {}".format(user.title(), computer_move.title()))
        #etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Your computer() function calls a random number. 
**So every time you call computer() in you code you are choosing 'at random' a completely new number.** 
Because there are only three answers, you may actually end up with the right answer quite often.

Think of calling the function as rolling a die (with 3 sides, whoa). So now your program looks like this:

```
def RollDice():
return random.choice(OPTIONS)
#...
while True:
    user = input("What do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors: ").lower()
    if user in OPTIONS:
        # Possible user time a user can succeeds rock beats scissor, scissors cuts paper, paper covers rock
        if user == RollDice:
            print("tie")

        elif user == 'rock' and RollDice == 'scissors':
            print("\nYou Won! {} crushes {}".format(user.title(),  RollDice.title()))

        elif user == 'scissors' and RollDice =='rock':
            print("\nComputer Won! {} crushes {}".format(RollDice.title(), user.title() ))
#...
```

Now you see what the problem is.
What you really want is to save the value of 'one' random choice at the very beginning of your if statement:

```
if user in OPTIONS:
    computerChoice = computer()
    if user == computerChoice:
        print("tie")

    elif user == 'rock' and computerChoice == 'scissors':
        print("\nYou Won! {} crushes {}".format(user.title(), computerChoice.title()))

    elif user == 'scissors' and computerChoice =='rock':
        print("\nComputer Won! {} crushes {}".format(computerChoice.title(), user.title() ))
    #....
```

That way you have one constant choice saved in a variable to call on.

P.S. It would also be better to use **raw_input** instead of **input** so that the program will automatically change the users input into a string.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer*, the answer has been given, this is merely to peak the interest in generalizing the game.

To make *any* type of Rock-Paper-Scissor game you can realize that it is in fact a round-robin table of wins.

For instance if you do this:

```
P-R-S..P-R-S
```

you can see that the previous letter *always* wins on the next letter.

Using this approach it becomes easy to create custom rock-paper-scissor games using look-around tables:

```
import random
from collections import OrderedDict

# Important to retain order of "kill"
OPTIONS = OrderedDict([('P', 'Paper'),
                       ('R', 'Rock'),
                       ('S', 'Scissors')])
# N_KILLS determines how many letters in front it is killing
N_KILLS = 1

OPTIONS = OrderedDict([('P', 'Princess'),
                       ('J', 'Knight'),
                       ('W', 'Wizard'),
                       ('D', 'Dragon'),
                       ('K', 'King')])
N_KILLS = 2


# Create lookup table
LOOKUP = OPTIONS.keys()
# Number of items
N_ITEMS = len(LOOKUP)

# Options to choose from
STR_OPTIONS = ' ,'.join( OPTIONS.values() )

def computer():
    return random.randint(0,N_ITEMS-1)

print("\n"+"-=-"*11)
print("Welcome to "+STR_OPTIONS)
print("              GAME")
print("   It's you vs. the computer!")
print("-=-"*11)
while True:

    # Convert user option to integer
    uidx = computer()

    if uidx >= 0:
        # Get computer index
        cidx = computer()

        d = cidx - uidx

        # Correct for wrap-arounds
        if d > N_KILLS: 
            d = d - N_ITEMS
        elif d < -N_KILLS:
            d = d + N_ITEMS

        print(' You choose: '+OPTIONS[LOOKUP[uidx]] + ' computer chooses: '+OPTIONS[LOOKUP[cidx]])

        if d == 0:
            print('   Tie ...')
        elif d > 0 and d <= N_KILLS:
            print('   You WIN ...')
        elif d < 0 and -d <= N_KILLS:
            print('   You LOOSE ...')
        else:
            # This will only occur if N_KILLS*2+1<N_ITEMS
            print('   Tie ...')
```

Not only is the code easier to read (in my opinion), but it becomes extremely easy to implement several new *games*. For instance check this amazing game out: http://www.umop.com/rps101.htm

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it correct, as has been mentioned, for each game, the call to `computer()` should only be made once. It would also make sense to display the two player's choices. Also as you are working in title case, it would make sense to convert everything to use that to avoid needing to call `.title()` so many times.

```
import random

OPTIONS = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
    # then check if the user lose's, wins ties

def computer():
    return random.choice(OPTIONS)

print("\n"+"-=-"*11)
print("Welcome to ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS")
print("              GAME")
print("   It's you Vs. the computer!")
print("-=-"*11)

while True:
    user_choice = input("\nWhat do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors: ").title()
    computer_choice = computer()
    print("User: {}   Computer: {}".format(user_choice, computer_choice))

    if user_choice in OPTIONS:
        # Possible user_choice time a user_choice can succeeds rock beats sicissor, sicissors cuts paper, paper covers rock
        if user_choice == computer_choice:
            print("tie")

        elif user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Scissors':
            print("You Won! {} crushes {}".format(user_choice, computer_choice))

        elif user_choice == 'Scissors' and computer_choice == 'Rock':
            print("Computer Won! {} crushes {}".format(computer_choice, user_choice ))

        elif user_choice == 'Scissors' and computer_choice == 'Paper':
            print("You Won! {} cuts {}".format(user_choice, computer_choice))

        elif user_choice == 'Paper' and computer_choice == 'Scissors':
            print("Computer Won! {} cuts {}".format(computer_choice, user_choice))

        elif user_choice == 'Paper' and computer_choice == 'Rock':
            print("You Won! {} covers {}".format(user_choice, computer_choice))

        elif user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Paper':
            print("Computer Won! {} covers {}".format(computer_choice, user_choice))
    else:
        print("Make sure you choose either Rock, Paper or Scissors")
```

So a game would look like:

```
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-
Welcome to ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS
              GAME
   It's you Vs. the computer!
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-

What do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors: rock
User: Rock   Computer: Scissors
You Won! Rock crushes Scissors
```